# How do you make a page sections in Html

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you make a page layout with horizontal sections but on the same page ? I want my page to have a body , and then the footer on another section(exactly Below the page) Like the one in this [Example](http://hackkings.org/)!

If you notice, the first page you see contains a background then when you scroll down, there are multiple sections but with no backgrounds. Please how is this achieved ? I will be glad if you can give examples too Thank you very much !

Comment: You can use plugins like this one: http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to use HTML and CSS.

Here is [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/eube8/)

### HTML

```
<header class="container global-header">
    Header
</header>

<section class="container about">
    About
</section>

<section class="container contact">
    Contact
</section>

<footer class="container global-footer">
    Footer
</footer>
```

### CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* look this up */
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

/* style what the sections have in common */
.container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

/* target specific sections */
.global-header {
    background-color: red;
}

.about {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: anything special about box-sizing ?

Comment: @sheriffderek Good job explaining this. I was reusing your fiddle to show him an example of what he's looking for but they closed it before  I had a chance to post it. 

He's looking for a fluid design. Here is your [fiddle in fluid](http://jsfiddle.net/eube8/3/) style

Comment: @LOTUSMS - my code is 100% fluid. It got closed because the question was basically - "can someone teach me html" - and that is too vague of a question for stack-overflow.

Comment: @aelor - Yes, box-sizing is very special. It declares that padding and borders width/size - be moved into the element instead of outside which adds to the overall size of the element. You can google it and see what Paul Irish has to say about it. It's awesome. I would give up code if it didn't exist.

Comment: Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/UAkLv/